# How to store fetch api record in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

Here I am simply getting my record from mysql database with the help of fetch api and then I am storing the record in the state and I have many records in DB but the problem is whenever fetchapi fetches new record it vipes out previous one but I don't want to lose previous record because I want to store all record in the array of objects like this `[{obj1},{obj2},{obj3}]`
so later on I can iterate with map so how can I deal with this problem:

```
  let [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const loadData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost/k-shop/load.php");
    const result = await response.json();
    setData([result]);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);
  console.log(data);
```

Comment: What about `setData([...data, result])`?

Answer (score 1):

Here problem was not in my react it was in my php code from where I was getting my DB result I corrected my php code and now its working perfectly